# Using Django CreateView without Form to Create Object

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am using classed based views with django 1.3 and am trying to figure out how to create an object without using the form. I do not need any user input to create the object but I am still getting an error message that the template is missing. Below is my current view where I have tried to subclass the form_valid method but its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class ReviewerCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Reviewer

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.role = 2
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A CreateView is a specialized view whose purpose is to display a form on GET and validate the form data and create a new object based on the form data on POST.

Since you don't need to display a form and process the form data, a CreateView is not the tool for your job.

You either need a plain old function-based view, or, if you prefer to use a class-based view, derive from View and override `get()` or `post()`. For example, adapting your sample code:

```
class ReviewerCreator(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         Reviewer(user=request.user, role=2).save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/your_success_url/')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I am using django-registration and have added the account creation logic to the activate function and its working properly.

Comment: it's bad practice to use GET method to create resources in backend. should use POST/PUT/PATCH

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe a view needs to do anything explicit with a form if it does not need one.

You can instantiate a Reviewer object. It's just a python object.

```
class ReviewerCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Reviewer

    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.role = 2
    self.object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```